# circuits in python, class not working

Tags: python

I am using a Python circuit simulator, which code is found at:

http://www.openbookproject.net/courses/python4fun/logic.html

with that I would like to simulate the circuit that is in the example which is:

[image]

so following the example, I have made a program like this:

```
from logic import *
def main():
    a=And("a1")
    a.C.monitor=1
    a.A.set(1)
    a.B.set(1)
    n=Not("n1")
    a.C.connect(n.A)
    n.B.monitor=1
    a.A.set(0)
```

giving me the following answer:

```
Connector a1-C set to 1
Connector a1-C set to 0
Connector n1-B set to True
```

For what I see, and because the variable monitor is turned "on", it first outputs the resuls of 1.1=1 and then because of the change that I made to the A input it displays the result of 0.1=0; the last answer is a True value because of the not gate.

I have a problem when I play with the input gates as following:

```
def main():
    a=And("a1")
    a.C.monitor=1
    a.A.set(0)
    a.B.set(0)
    n=Not("n1")
    a.C.connect(n.A)
    n.B.monitor=1
    a.B.set(1)
```

the only answer that display is:

```
Connector a1-C set to 0
```

it does not even evaluate the not gate, what is wrong the code?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You never change the *input* of your `NOT` gate. As the simulator only monitors states change -- nothing is displayed for that gate.

At the "start" of your program, the output of the `AND` gate is at 0:

```
a=And("a1")
a.C.monitor=1
a.A.set(0)
a.B.set(0)
```

Setting *only one* leg to 1 does not change the output of that `AND`. You have to set the two inputs to 1 to trigger a state change:

```
n=Not("n1")
n.B.monitor=1
a.C.connect(n.A)
a.B.set(1)
a.A.set(1)
```

---

Apparently that simple simulator does not monitor the "change" due to setting the initial state.

Adding a bunch of `print(n.B.value)` showed that state change is only triggered when *input* change. Not when connected:

```
n=Not("n1")
print(n.B.value)
n.B.monitor=1
print(n.B.value)
a.C.connect(n.A)
print(n.B.value)
a.B.set(1)
print(n.B.value)
a.A.set(1)
print(n.B.value)
```

Displaying:

```
None
None
None                      <-- after connect
None                      <-- after a.B.set(1)
Connector a1-C set to 1
Connector n1-B set to False
False                     <-- after a.A.set(1)
```

Comment: I understand, but the AND gate is connected to the NOT gate, so I want the change to occur when I modify the inputs from the AND gate

Comment: My mistake: I read the connect parameters in the wrong order. Check my edit.